# Queue Member (Partner User) not able to access Task

Tags: sharing, tasks, activities, partner-communities, queue

The system admin is creating a Task which is Assigned to a Queue. This queue consists of two partner Community Users. The expectation would be that the queue members would have access to the Task. However after logging into the Community as the Partner User, the user is not able to see the Task.

If this is not possible, is there any other workaround to assign Tasks to more than one Partner Community User. The Users should have View and Edit access to  the Task.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I have the same problem.